# FullCalendar month view is only showing events for the current month

Tags: drupal-7, fullcalendar

I imported a couple thousand events into Drupal 7 Events content type. They're all published and I can view each event individually. But, in the Month view, only events from the current month are appearing. If I click through to other months, nothing appears.

I just realized it's doing this for other views also (week and day).

I'm guessing that I have some type of filter set incorrectly or something. Any ideas?

Comment: A screenshot of the view would be nice.